# Theming of certain view block pager

Tags: 6, theming, paging

i know how to theme pager on the whole site with a theme_pager().
But how to theme a certain pager in a view block?
By default pager shows **← 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9...100 →**

I need **← 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...100 →**

How is that possible to theme pager just in one block not whole site?

Comment: `theme_pager()` has the `$quantity` param that let you specify the number of pages displayed. In the case of a view, I think you can create your own view template and set this `$quantity` value on that template. I never tried this but I think it should work.

Comment: can you throw any examples?